# Change Directory with Windows 16bits API

Tags: windows, api, assembly, 16-bit

I write in MASM 6.0 (Assembly API Windows 16 bits)
I want to change dir in my code.
I'm using DOS3Call function (faster than int 21h)

```
mov dx,OFFSET dir_user
mov ah,3bh
invoke DOS3Call

;dir_user is the user's work directory, like "c:\prog"
```

With this function, i can change dir, but i want know if have any API that can do it for me without use interrupts.

I need a 16 bits API, in 32 bits I know how to do it.

Can anybody help me?

Sorry by English, i'm not american...

Comment: afaik, you have to use `int 21h`.

Comment: DOS3Call does the same thing.

Comment: You need to use interrupts or DOS3Call.  Anything else would be poking at OS internals which is a bad idea.  (I would add - if you have something working, why change it?)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Interrupts are the only way on today's 32- and 64-bit systems.

Comment: Dude, he's talking about Win16.

Comment: @Joshua - show me a 16-bit operating system you can program with MASM. 16-bit is obsolete, which is why I mentioned the others.

Comment: ever heard of DR-DOS? Once a product that was such a threat to Microsoft that they inserted a special test in their application software to test if it was running on MS-DOS or DR-DOS and in the latter case issued a message that the underlying OS was not MS-DOS? Still alive and appreciated, see www.drdos.com and check out their client list. You learn something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

Win16 uses the DOS API for filesystems. The syscall gate is int 21h.

Check the C standard library. I never actually invoked the syscall gate directly in Win16 programming.

Comment: The only C function I could find was chdir that changed the directory. It was introduced with Windows 95 so, if I'm not mistaken, it was a 32-bit function. I'm not sure if there was a 16-bit version, but that may be a good place to start.